# How to join one table with grouped values from different query?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a models like this:

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    visable_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    recipe_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website_url = models.URLField()


class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class UserSubs(models.Model):
    subscription = models.ForeignKey(Subscription, to_field='visable_name')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, to_field='username')
```

And I want to prepare simple ranking, so I came up with something like this:

```
rank = UserSubs.objects.values('subscription').
                        annotate(total=Count('user')).
                        order_by('-total')`
```

what gives:

```
>> rank
[
   {'total': 3, 'subscription': u'onet'}, 
   {'total': 2, 'subscription': u'niebezpiecznik'}, 
   {'total': 1, 'subscription': u'gazeta'}
]
```

what I need, is similar list of full objects:

```
[
   {'total': 3, 'subscription': <Subscription: onet>}, 
   {'total': 2, 'subscription': <Subscription: niebezpiecznik>}, 
   {'total': 1, 'subscription': <Subscription: gazeta>}
]
```

I am not sure, whether 'select_related' will be helpful here, but I can't figured out how to use it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to build your query from `Subscription` because you need it:

```
Subscription.objects.annotate(total=models.Count('usersubs')).order_by('-total')
```

Comment: thats will give me: `[<Subscription: onet>, <Subscription: niebezpiecznik>, <Subscription: gazeta.pl>]`. Is there a way to also get `total` for each subscription?

Comment: Never mind! Now I see, that `total` is now attribute of each subscription :) Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use dict and list comprehension, and filter this as simple python objects:

```
d = {sub.visable_name: sub for sub in Subscriptions.objects.all()}
new_rank = [
  {
    'total': row['total'], 
    'subscriptions': d[row['subscriptions']]
  } 
  for row in rank
]
```

what will give:

```
>> new_rank
[
  {'total': 3, 'subscriptions': <Subscriptions: onet>}, 
  {'total': 2, 'subscriptions': <Subscriptions: niebezpiecznik>}, 
  {'total': 1, 'subscriptions': <Subscriptions: gazeta.pl>}
]
```